# how to implement deep copying of queue in python

Tags: python, data-structures, queue

I want to maintain two queues, Queue A is for pop , Queue B is for backup,  so if i pop all objects out from A, how do I restore Queue A from B?

```
while (still has input)
     A.push(input)
     B.push(input)

while A is not empty
      A.pop()
```

Then how do I restore A from B???  In the meantime, I still want to keep B as my backup.

I know some very stupid way to do it , like assign one more queue C and then pop all Bout. And then restore B from queue C

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way is to use the `copy` module.

```
import copy

while (still has input)
    A.push(input)
    B.push(input)

while A is not empty
    A.pop()

A = copy.deepcopy(B)
```

Comment: do you mean A = copy.deepcopy(B) ?